# data-bind="click" function not work with "this"?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, inline-functions

I am trying to get something to happen to an element when its is clicked on using *knockout.js* and *jquery*. I can change the css of a different element like background of the body with this code but not if i try to use `this.css(something)` or `$(this).css(something)`

```
<h4>Places</h4>
<ul data-bind="foreach: city">
    <li data-bind="click: function(){$(this).css('color','yellow')}"><span data-bind="text: city"></span>, <span data-bind="text: state"></span>
    </li>
</ul>

function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.city = ko.observableArray([
            { city: 'Richmond', state: 'VA' },
            { city: 'Dallas', state: 'TX' },
            { city: 'Los Angeles', state: 'CA' }
    ]);    
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

http://codepen.io/ntibbs/pen/PPdEVJ

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense for the objects in your array to have an observable property and then use `style` binding and have your click function work to set that property. That would be more MVVM. As it is now, `this` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: im fairly new to MVVM knockoutjs. My end goal will to be click on a LI element and zoom into a marker on google maps. Would doing that be possible with what you just mentioned ? if so ill look into that.

Comment: Are you just trying to highlight a "selected item"? Use the `css` binding for that.

Comment: In any binding, `$element` refers to the current element. See http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html

Answer (score 1):

Knockout passes in 2 parameters to your function handler for events (See [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html)). So you can do something like this: `data-bind="click: function(data,e){$(e.target).css('color','yellow')}"`

Answer (score 1):

As @Matt Burland mentioned, the "Knockout" way of doing this would be to have a `color` property in your view model that gets bound to an element using the `style` binding.

```
<li data-bind="style: { color: color() }">
```

But if you really need a way to reference the element inside a `click` binding's action, you'd use `event.target`.

```
<li data-bind="click: function(context, event){ $(event.target).css('color','yellow') }">
```

Answer (score 1):

Like @Matt Burland pointed out in the comment, in order to make it truly MVVM and avoid direct DOM manipulation, you can add a flag on individual objects (city) to toggle when selected or not. I have modified your codepen to show what I am saying

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaqqdL

```
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.city = ko.observableArray([
            { city: 'Richmond', state: 'VA'},
            { city: 'Dallas', state: 'TX' },
            { city: 'Los Angeles', state: 'CA'}
    ]);    

  ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.city(),function(item){
      item.isSelected = ko.observable(false);
    item.toggle=function(){
      item.isSelected(!item.isSelected());
    };
  });
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

and mark up would be

```
<h4>Places</h4>
<ul data-bind="foreach: city">
    <li data-bind="css:{selectedcity:isSelected},click: toggle"><span data-bind="text: city"></span>, <span data-bind="text: state"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```